# Dimple JS: Filter data but not Legend

Tags: dimple.js

I'm trying to draw a chart with a series added, and an interactive legend with all options, but I want the chart to load with data filtered down to only one option in the legend.

This is the same question as was answered in [dimple.js: filter data, but not legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026693/dimple-js-filter-data-but-not-legend) . However, the links to the solution are no longer available.

Can someone please repost the solution?

Comment: why you created separate question? ask for the help in original answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dimple.js: filter data, but not legend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026693/dimple-js-filter-data-but-not-legend)

Comment: @Farside, I wasn't sure if it was OK to ask for help in the original question - the "Answer" box tip says to avoid asking for clarification. Hence I posted a new question with a link to the original question.

Comment: you are correct. At the same time It's ok to ask in the **comments** for the clarification or to ask to update the link with the solution, which went dead.